# Regex in PHP to modify strings within a text

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to add h4 tags to all subtitles within a text, these subtitles always start with roman number followed by a point and end with two line breaks. Sadly the following regex doesn't work despite me trying for hours. Any ideas what to fix?

```
    $string = "<h1>Is Buying Property During a Recession a Smart Financial Move?</h1><p><br>I. Introduction<br><br> In this article, we will explore the benefits and risks of buying property during a recession, as well as provide tips and considerations for making an informed decision.<br><br>II. What is a Recession?<br><br>A recession is a period of ..";

    $pattern = "/^([IVXLCDM]+\.).*<br><br>$/m"; // the /m modifier enables multiline mode
    
    // replace each matched string with the same string enclosed in <h4> tags
    $new_string = preg_replace($pattern, "<h4>$0</h4>", $string);
    
    echo $new_string;
```

Comment: But your string has no lines. Remove the anchors, `^` and `$`. And then you do not need any `m` flag. Also, use lazy `.*?`. So, something like `/[IVXLCDM]+\..*?<br><br>/` (and you see that you need no group here since you are using `$0` backreference). See https://3v4l.org/OLvT3 and https://regex101.com/r/XU5ZYr/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, this improved the result. Now the whole content of <h4> subtitle 1 -> text -> subtitle 2 </h4> has the h4 tags wrapped around. So I guess the problem is now the two line breaks for the closing h4 aren't recognized correctly.